# Pandas - stacked bar chart with column values for stacking

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a data set with three sets of data: class type, neighborhood, and visibility.

[image: sample table]

I'm trying to create a bar chart that is *both* stacked and unstacked -- stacked by visibility, lined up by neighborhood. So basically, I'm looking for a combination of the unstacked-ness of this chart:

[image: sample chart 1]

```
nbvis_gb = nbvis.sort_values(by=['visibility'],ascending=False).groupby(by='visibility',sort=False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(14,8),sharey=True)

for (i, j), ax,color in zip(nbvis_gb,ax.flatten(),colors_hood):
    print(j['class'].values)
    title = str(i)
    j.plot.bar(ax=ax,colors=colors_hood)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
    #ax.set_ylim(0,1.05)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
    ax.set_xticklabels(j['class'].values)
    ax.legend_.remove()


ax.legend(loc=8,fontsize=20,ncol=4,bbox_to_anchor=(0,-.45))
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=2)
fig.suptitle('Visibility of containers by class and neighborhood',y=1.03,fontsize=24)
```

and the stacked-ness of this chart:

[image]

```
nbvis.unstack()['Neighborhood 1'].plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Elizabeth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `melt` and `pivot_table` of your dataframe to create a multi-index datafame aligned to your graph dimensions. Below outputs graph to screen and saves figure to png image in same folder using seaborn's color scheme. Of course adjust graph settings as needed.

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn

np.random.seed(444)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(['bucket (1)', 'flower pot (2)', 'tarp (3)', 'trash (6)', 'toy (7)',
                                'piping/tubing (9)', 'other (10)'],
                               ['visible containers', 'partial or not visible containers'])), 
                  columns=['class', 'visibility']).assign(Neighborhood1 = abs(np.random.randn(14)),
                                                          Neighborhood2 = abs(np.random.randn(14)),
                                                          Neighborhood3 = abs(np.random.randn(14)),
                                                          Neighborhood4 = abs(np.random.randn(14)))
```

**Graphing**

```
seaborn.set()

def runplot(pvtdf):        
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(mdf['Neighborhood'].unique()))

    for i, n in enumerate(mdf['Neighborhood'].unique()):
        pvtdf.xs(n).plot(ax=axes[i], kind='bar', stacked=True, edgecolor='w', 
                figsize=(20,8), width=0.5, fontsize = 12, 
                title='{} - Visibility of containers \n by class and neighborhood'.format(n))
        axes[i].title.set_size(16)

    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig('Output.png')
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

# MELT LONG
mdf = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['class', 'visibility'], var_name='Neighborhood')

# PIVOT WIDE
pvtdf = mdf.pivot_table(index= ['Neighborhood', 'class'], columns='visibility', values='value')

runplot(pvtdf, n)

plt.close()
```

**Output**

[image: Neighborhood Graphs]

Comment: Hey Parfait, this is pretty close & I'm keen on doing this automatically (e.g. without having to set the location of the bars), but I am trying to get them all on the same graph like brian caffeey's

Answer (score 1):

here's one way you could do this. I used some dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"class":['bucket', 'pot', 'tarp', 'trash', 'toy', 'tubing', 'other','bucket', 'pot', 'tarp', 'trash', 'toy', 'tubing', 'other',], 
                   "visability":["visable", "visable","visable","visable","visable","visable","visable", "not visable","not visable","not visable","not visable","not visable","not visable","not visable",],
                   "n1":np.random.random(size=14), 
                   "n2":np.random.random(size=14), 
                   "n3":np.random.random(size=14), 
                   "n4":np.random.random(size=14)})
```

I think the trick is to use `bottom`:

```
N=7
width = 0.095
w = 0
ind = np.arange(N) + .15 
classes = ['bucket', 'pot', 'tarp', 'trash', 'toy', 'tubing', 'other']
neighborhoods = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

top_colors = ['#ff9999', '#9999ff', '#e6b3ff', '#66ff66']
bottom_colors = ['#b30000', '#000066', '#7700b3', '#004d00']

for i, n in enumerate(neighborhoods):
    vis = df[(df.visability == "visable")][n]
    non_vis = df[df.visability == "not visable"][n]

    rect1 = ax.bar(ind+w, vis, float(width), color=top_colors[i])
    rect2 = ax.bar(ind+w, non_vis, width, color=bottom_colors[i], bottom=vis)
    w += 0.15

extra_space = 0.05
ax.set_xticks(ind+width+xtra_space)
ax.set_xticklabels(('bucket', 'pot', 'tarp', 'trash', 'toy', 'tubing', 'other',))

ax.set_title('Visability of container types by class')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!! Pretty clean -- this is what I'm looking for, though I don't necessarily love setting the width/ticks

Comment: @E.Case thanks! I'm glad it is helpful for you. Yes, there is probably a better way to set the ticks and width. It seems like there are a number of ways you could go about adding labels and legends, so I just stuck to the stacking/grouping part.